# question about selectors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following:

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;
    SEL sel = @selector(profilePop:withUser:) withObject:tapGesture withObject:message.creator;
    tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:sel];
```

and I want it to be able to call:

```
- (void)profilePop:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer withUser:(Login *)user
{
    //some code here
}
```

but why isn't it doing so?

Comment: Is profilePop:withUser: in self's interface?

Comment: How would the handler expect to receive the `(Login *)user` parameter?

Comment: I have edited the code above,sorry for that, now it's giving me an error that sel needs a ']' ?

Comment: so how would I change it

Comment: then how do I define the objects that is passed in to the parameter arguments?

Comment: @adit, I deleted my comments; you've got some much better answers already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A selector only knows about its name and any parameter names, not its arguments.

`UIGestureRecognizer` only accepts actions which take in either zero or one argument of its type.

In order to do what you want, you'll need to write a wrapper method to pass off a `Login` instance to `profilePop:withUser:`.

So, you'd write something like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(profilePopWrapper:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];


//....

- (void) profilePopWrapper:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gr {
    Login *someUser = ...;
    [self profilePop:gr withUser:someUser];
}
```

Comment: the issue is that the Login* can obly be extracted within that function that I set the tapgesturerecognizer

Comment: @adit Why can you not store it in an instance variable?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW14), action messages must take a specific form

```
- (void)handleGesture
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
```

You can't just use any arbitrary selector as an action; it must be a selector that conforms to one of the patterns above.

Comment: what would be an appropriate way then if I want to pass in an object to that gesture recognizer?

Comment: The action that you pass into the gesture recognizer isn't a method in the recognizer, it's a method in the recognizer's target. When the recognizer decides that its gesture has been performed, it sends the action message to its target. Furthermore, you're using UITapGestureRecognizer, which doesn't have a way to an object and wouldn't know what to do with the object if it did. So, I've told you why your method isn't getting called as the tap recognizer's action. Perhaps you could take some time to clarify your question and explain what you're really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Use single argument in @selector function this way.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(profilePop:)];
```

Because UITapGestureRecognizer can identifies only tap recognition.