# Handle tap gesture with an argument iphone / ipad

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160489/handle-tap-gesture-with-an-argument-iphone-ipad) with the only exception - my ImageView appears at the same place inside the window with different content in it. Content has unique identifier which I want to use to call content-specific actions.

To quickly recap, the guy is looking for a way to pass a parameter into the selector section of the initWithTarget method.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(handleTapGesture:itemSKU:)];
```

How can I pass an attribute to the handleTapGesture method or how do I read the unique value otherwise?

Any thoughts appreciated.

EDIT: The content is being pulled from a database and is different every time. The unique identifier is pretty much like an SSN - doesn't repeat.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811979/question-about-selectors) is exactly what I want to do, but nobody seems to know the answer. There should be a way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set the `UIImageView` tag property with your content identifier, and then read that information form the selector.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
imageView.tag = 0;
```

And then:

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if( ((UIImageView *) sender.view).tag == 0 ) // Check the identifier
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion - saves a lot of trouble too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the `UIImageView` and add whatever values (as properties) and methods you will need.

```
@interface UIImageViewWithId: UIImageView

@property int imageId;

@end
```

Then, if you want to be even MORE awesome you may want to encapsulate your behavior in this "widget"'s implementation.  This will keep your `ViewController` nice and clean, and allow you to use this widget across multiple controllers.

```
@implementation UIImageViewWithId

@synthesize imageId;

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
   NSLog("Hey look! It's Id #%d", imageId);
}

@end
```

Then just delegate the tap to the individual `UIImageViewWithId`s

```
UIImageViewWithId *imageView = [[UIImageViewWithId ... ]]
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: imageView  action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
```